# How to select text always precisely from mouse like we can do always from keyboard?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, mouse

How to select text always precisely from mouse like we can do always from keyboard?

Comment: I guess you're referring to the mouse making some automatic adjustments to your selection, like maybe it's always selecting whole words or never including spaces?

Comment: yes some time it select something which i don't want to select.on starting and ending point

Comment: Should i press any key along with mouse selection to make precise selection?

Comment: Some programs like Microsoft Office have some "smart selection" preferences, or maybe that is just "smart edit" and only applies to cutting and pasting then. I guess we need more detail on when it's occurring. (Note the "edit" link underneath your question!)

Comment: i can select Edit button from right side but not from left

Comment: Errr, I was trying to imply that you could *click* that "edit" link and add your comments to your question, for clarification... :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the mouse *can* give the same accuracy as the keyboard, but maybe it's because I use a cheap mouse.

A two step approach works best for me:

1. use the mouse to carefully select the first few characters of the text, then release the mouse button and
2. use the arrow keys to move the cursor while holding down the shift key, to 'fine-tune' the selection.

Answer (score 1):

> i can select Edit button from right side but not from left

Not being able to select that "edit" link is caused by the layout in the web site, in combination with it being a clickable link, and in combination with the browser you're using. In Firefox and IE8, you can toggle "[Caret Browsing](http://techie-buzz.com/tips-and-tricks/surf-webpages-like-a-text-file-or-document-in-firefox-and-ie-8.html)" by hitting F7. This places a moveable cursor in web pages, allowing you to select text with the keyboard.

But this is just a specific example. Other programs might have their own "smart" selection mechanism implemented. Like some word processors might always select whole words or never include spaces when selecting using a mouse. I am not aware of some operating system-specific behaviour.